# control momentum scrolling in chromium

Tags: google-chrome, raspbian, chromium

I'm running chromium 65 directly under X on raspian 65. 
The input device is a touchscreen. 
Currently momentum/inertial scrolling is only possible using two fingers. When I use one finger chrome stops scrolling when I lift the finger. 
How can I activate scrolling with one finger like on Android/iOS?